# Nested JSON path using TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter not working (possibly due to RAD Studio 10.4 upgrade)

Tags: json, delphi, rad-studio

In an existing project I need to parse some JSON into a dataset using `TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter`, but I can't get nested fields to work.

As a simplified example, let's say the data is structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "Animals",
      "display": true 
    },
    "label": "Horse" 
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "Animals",
      "display": true 
    },
    "label": "Elephant" 
  },
  ...and so on...
]
```

The dataset has fields with the following field names: `label`, `category.name` and `category.display`.

Only the `label` gets successfully retrieved from the JSON, but the nested properties in the `category` JSON object do not. The `TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter` has `NestedElements = true` and `NestedElementsDepth = 2` (I also tried 0 and 1).

I'm pretty sure this has worked before upgrading to RAD Studio 10.4, but I'm not 100% sure if it started failing before upgrading to 10.4 or as a result of the upgrade.

I can't really find any good info on how to use nested fields, but I seem to remember reading somewhere that you're supposed to separate the path with dots. Any ideas why it is not working?